# Java file can't find DeviceEventManagerModule when compiling debug with Java

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have been trying to write a module for react-native thats should call a Javascript method when the phone recevies a call. But when i run the command `react-native run-android` the `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` craches with the following error.

```
CallListenerModule.java:44 error: package DeviceEventManagerModule does not exist (DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
```

this is the CallListenerModule class:

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;


import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

import android.util.Log;

public class CallListenerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    BroadcastReceiverCustom broadcastRecevier;

    ReactContext context;

    public CallListenerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        context = reactContext;
        broadcastRecevier = new BroadcastReceiverCustom(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
        public String getName() {
        return "CallListenerModule";
    }

    public void sendCallEvent(String incomingNumber){
        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("Number", incomingNumber);
        sendEvent(context, "CallRecevied", params);
    }


    private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                        String eventName,
                        WritableMap params) {
        reactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(eventName, params);
    }
}
```

I have search the great internet for a solution for this problem but with no luck. The `sendEvent` method is copied from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript). I removed the `@Nullable` from the params parameter because it casued another error and I do not intend on sending event without a parameter.

This is my first post on SO so any constructive criticism is appreciated :)

Comment: You are missing the import statement: `import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule`

Comment: Thanks!! It did the trick. Is there an easy way to figure out what packages to import? import statements is not always included in the documentation.

Comment: Use an Java IDE with automatic code checking/compiling - missing imports are displayed as error - usually with suggestions which class to import.

Comment: Ok. I am using Sublime text 3 at the moment but it dosen't seem to help with that. I will check if there is another one i could use instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer so I can mark is as the solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot to import the class `com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule`. Therefore you can solve your problem by adding the following line:

`import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule`